# HighCharts/Maps: How to display values lower than a certain value appear different from the rest of the graphic?

Tags: highcharts, visualization, data-visualization, highmaps

Consider a world choropleth map, showing population densities across countries. I need to get countries with population size less than 1 million not be a part of the choropleth, unlike the rest of the countries in the map. Currently, I am just not passing through any values so these countries are displayed as "No data." If I pass their values, they retain the same property as the rest of the other countries and are displayed in the choropleth color scales. Is there a way to get these countries with low population (<1m) appear different than "No data" and not have them colored based on their population densities but make them appear in a different color based on if their population is below 1m.

I am working with confidential data, hence providing a generic example of population and density. I looked through the documentation, but couldn't find a accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set colorAxis min to 1 million and define stops like:

```
            stops: [
                [0, '#ff0000'],
                [1e-8, '#ff0000'],
                [1e-7, '#EFEFFF'],
                [0.67, '#4444FF'],
                [1, '#000022']
            ]
```

That way red start will not be visible on colorAxis (smaller than 1 pixel), but will be applied to all points with value below colorAxis min.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bc5zrfoh/